# CKEditor 3.6.6: Add spoiler button by pasting HTML source code

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am an employee at a research center. I did not create the website for my research center, but I was given the ability to add new landing pages to the website. I can add various Drupal building blocks (e.g., Paragraph type: Text Block), and I can add/edit text through a CKEditor (version 3.6.6).

In a given text block, I would like to be able to add a spoiler "Show/Hide" button that users can click to display/hide a piece of text on the page. I found a CKEditor plugin for this (https://github.com/zetamen/ckeditor-spoiler). However, I am not an administrator on the website, and I cannot add new plugins.

I found that I can paste HTML code directly into CKEditor by clicking on the Source Code button. Is there a way to write some HTML code that can be pasted into CKEditor to create a functional spoiler "Show/Hide" button? I am not experienced in HTML or CKEditor, and I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: how long does your spoiler need to be? you want it to deploy on click, or only while the user clicks it, or only on mouse hover?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what level of security does CKEditor have in regards to your input; usually, things like javascript might get automatically deleted to avoid javascript injection attacks.

If your text is unfiltered and it allows you to enter script tags, you could use this CDN:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/houdini/dist/js/houdinijs.polyfills.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {
var disclosure = new Houdini('[data-houdini]');
})();
</script>

<div data-houdini data-houdini-button="Show More" id="show-me">
  <p>Now you see me, now you don't.</p>
</div>
```

=======

Supposing the above is impossible with your current permissions...

I'm going to suppose you at least can add CSS styles. In this case, you could use the following HTML5 and CSS3 to create a collapsible block of text:

```css
.wrap-collabsible {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem 0;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.lbl-toggle {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #FAE042;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lbl-toggle:hover {
  color: #7C5AFF;
}



.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-3px);
}

.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .25s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle:checked + .lbl-toggle + .collapsible-content {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.collapsible-content .content-inner {
  background: rgba(250, 224, 66, .2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 224, 66, .45);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-collabsible">
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle">Click my title</label>
  <div class="collapsible-content">
    <div class="content-inner">
      <p>
        Because of the custom data model used in the editor, the source mode makes little sense in CKEditor 5. CKEditor 5 is a content editor, not a page builder and, unless some editor feature (plugin) supports some particular kind of HTML (or any other input format), it will not be accepted as content.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that we mask a checkbox with CSS to keep the state of the button.

You can try entering the CSS in a  tag and see if it's allowed, or you could try to include all of this in inline CSS "style" attributes if that doesn't work.